# Creating POJO for Retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

My json response is

```
[
  {
    "responseValue":"error"
  },
  {
    "responseData":
    {
      "erroCode":"1",
      "errorDesc":"Invalid Client Key"
    }
  }
]
```

What is the structure of POJO class?
And i am using Retrofit 1.9.0 . 
i am using gson converter.
And how should i declare the function in adapter interface and how to call ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the below link, It has all sorts of json to pojo options.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: hi , i already used that link . i pasted my json response over there   selected the gson option and it create two classes for me because my json response is an array like structure. I took that 2 classes and added to project. and set the api class Callback to one class . But when run the code it gives error of BEGIN_OBJECT is expected but found BEGIN_ARRAY etc...

Comment: What should be the declaration of the function in the interface , and how can i call it?

Answer (score 0):

http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

```
    {
        "status": "success",
        "message": "Records found.",
        "data": {
            "verify_details": [
                {
                    "key": "Hologram No",
                    "value": "J10001"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Retailer",
                    "value": null
                }
            ]
        }
    }


package com.holostik.esecure.pojo;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NumbersOfScanPojo {

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;

    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;

    private Data data;

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public class Data {
        public List<NumbersOfScanPojo.Verify_details> verify_details = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<Verify_details> getVerify_details() {
            return verify_details;
        }

        public void setVerify_details(List<Verify_details> verify_details) {
            this.verify_details = verify_details;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClassPojo [verify_details = " + verify_details + "]";
        }
    }


    public class Verify_details {
        @SerializedName("key")
        private String key;

        @SerializedName("value")
        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClassPojo [value = " + value + ", key = " + key + "]";
        }
    }

}
```